# C#: Dictionary values to hashset conversion

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashset

Please, suggest the shortest way to convert `Dictionary<Key, Value>` to `Hashset<Value>`

Is there built-in **ToHashset()** LINQ extension for IEnumerables ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var yourSet = new HashSet<TValue>(yourDictionary.Values);
```

Or, if you prefer, you could knock up your own simple extension method to handle the type inferencing. Then you won't need to explicitly specify the `T` of the `HashSet<T>`:

```
var yourSet = yourDictionary.Values.ToHashSet();

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.ToHashSet<T>(null);
    }

    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question and answer doesn't make sense to me.  According to MSDN, a HashSet cannot contain duplicate elements and should be thought of as a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> collection without values.  It doesn't make sense to take all the values from a Dictionary and assign them to a HashSet to me.

Comment: Unfortunately, a KeyCollection object is not the same as a HashSet object, despite how much I wish it were so.

Comment: Keeping in mind this question is 5 years old; I agree with @ChristopherPainter. What's the point? What would make much more sense as far as uniqueness is concerned (albeit not the answer to this particular question) is: `new HashSet<TKey>(myDictionary.Keys)`.

Answer (score 5):

`new HashSet<Value>(YourDict.Values);`