# Convert Dictionary to HashEntry

Tags: c#, redis

I am trying to use hashSet method and it needs HashEntry[] array.

```
HashSet(RedisKey key, HashEntry[] hashFields, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None);
```

I am trying to do this, but this obviously is not working...

I have Dictionary value

```
  HashEntry[] hash = new HashEntry[value.Count]();
  int index = 0;
  foreach (var item in value)
  {
        hash[index].Name = item.Key;
        hash[index].Value = item.Value;
        index++;
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `HashEntry` is immutable; you need:

```
hash[index++] = new HashEntry(item.Key, item.Value);
```

Or perhaps more convenienty:

```
var fields = dictionary.Select(
    pair => new HashEntry(pair.Key, pair.Value)).ToArray();
```

Out of curiosity, what is the *exact* type of `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` here? It could be reasonable to add a few overloads for convenience. There are already some convenience methods in the other direction, such as `ToDictionary(...)` and `ToStringDictionary(...)`.

Comment: it's  Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: It would be nice to see these convenience methods for major primitive types like int, guid, double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

var result = new HashSet(dictionarySet.Values);

Also refer below link:

[C#: Dictionary values to hashset conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180030/c-dictionary-values-to-hashset-conversion)

Comment: This question is not talking about `HashSet<>`